# Cross-country words!

Tags: geography, cryptic-crosswords, crosswords

This is my first crossword, so I'd be grateful for any feedback. All the clues are names of countries.

[image: crossword]

### Across

6A. The loving start of Lady Jessica (6)
8A. Dock you, girl (8)
9A. Long Joanna (9)
10A. Nasty men from a bird beneath darkness, perhaps (12)
11A. Four Greek teens are coming round (6)
13A. I get it back around (7)
14A. A bird beneath darkness (6)
15A. Land of freedom, apparently (7)
16A. Either spicy or cold (5)
17A. Mixed precipitation (4)

### Down

1D. Around 22 yards (5)
2D. TV man without insole in war zone (7)
3D. MP longs for home in Runnymede (11)
4D. No longer a virgin (4)
5D. Takeaway (4)
7D. Almost a snake moving backwards (6)
8D. The land of long sticks and clean shoes (6)
10D. Sunburnt wackily (8)
12D. Ageless giant mammals (5)
16D. A paper circle (4)

Comment: 8 and 12 Across don't exist in the puzzle; I think the clue numbers for 8-15 need to be relabeled. Same with some of the Down clues.

Comment: I've solved about 11 of these, but I have to be somewhere the rest of the night, and I'm sure it'll be solved when I get back. Some of these clues are really clever! Good luck to everybody!

Comment: @VictorHenry Sorry about the clue mislabelling! I thought I'd made a serious mistake, but it was just a problem with SE. I put the right clue numbers (6,8,9, and so on), but SE interpreted them as just consecutive numbers (so the output was 6,7,8, and so on). Very annoying - I might raise it as a bug on Meta. Sorry again, and thanks for your interest! :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My attempt:

6A

> FRANCE - This one is a bit of a punt, I had to look it up to make any sense of it - Lady Jessica is a character in Dune (with a reputation for romance - thanks rand al'thor), played by Francesca Annis in the film version. Start of FRANCESCA is FRANCE

8A

> PORTUGAL - PORT (dock) U (you) GAL (girl)

9A

> ARGENTINA - Joanna is a female form of John (thanks for the pointer rand al'thor). 'Long John' references Long John Silver. Argentina is 'land of silver'

10A

> TURKMENISTAN - TURK MEN (men from a 'bird beneath darkness' - see 14A). ISTAN is nearly an anagram of 'nasty' so it could be 'turn nasty'

11A

> MEXICO - XI (fourteenth Greek 'four Greek teens' letter), inside an anagram of COME (are coming)? Not completely sure

13A

> NIGERIA - Anagram of IREGAIN (I get it back)

14A

> TURKEY - A bird. Turkey is south of (beneath) the Black Sea (darkness) (thanks for the hint rand al'thor)

15A

> LIBERIA - Means 'Land of the free'

16A

> CHILE - Chilli (spicy) or chilly (cold)

17A

> IRAN - Anagram of RAIN (precipitation)

1D

> CHINA - Anagram of CHAIN which is a unit of length of 22 yards

2D

> VIETNAM - Anagram of TELEVISION MAN without the letters from INSOLE

3D

> PHILIPPINES - PHILIP (Philip Hammond, British MP for Runnymede) PINES (longs for)

4D

> PERU - Anagram of PURE (virgin)

5D

> TOGO - To go (takeaway)

7D

> BRAZIL - LIZARD backwards, replacing the D

8D

> POLAND - Sounds like POLE LAND (land of long sticks). Also you would clean your shoes with POLISH

10D

> TANZANIA - TAN (sunburnt) ZANIA (a bit like zany - 'wacky')

12D

> WALES - WHALES (giant mammals) without the H (aitch-less which sounds like 'ageless' - thanks for the hint Len / rand al'thor)

16D

> CHAD - A paper circle (a word known to no-one until the hanging chad scandal of the 2000 US presidential elections)`

As pointed out by VictorHenry the clues need to be relabelled. Otherwise thank you, I enjoyed that - a few bits of GK and some nice wordplay.

Comment: Sorry about the clue mislabelling! I thought I'd made a serious mistake, but it was just a problem with SE. I put the right clue numbers (6,8,9, and so on), but SE interpreted them as just consecutive numbers (so the output was 6,7,8, and so on). Very annoying - I might raise it as a bug on Meta.

Comment: Anyway, more to the point, well done! :-) You've got all the clues right, but you might want to look again at the explanations for 9A (Long Joanna is a female version of...?), 10A and 14A (what is Turkey beneath?), 2D, 8D, and 12D.

Comment: Thanks for your pointers. I've updated 9A, 10A, 14A and 8D, but I can't think of anything further for 2D and 12D

Comment: Re. 6A, the "loving" is just a reference to France's reputation for romance. Re. 2D, what is TV short for? Re. 12D, "age" sounds like H - I think this is what @Len is saying too? (I've always seen H spelled as aitch rather than ach, but there's no doubt it's a weird letter to spell!) Also, please could you format the answer more nicely so that we don't have to keep scrolling left and right to read it?

Comment: Thanks all, the television thing had just clicked a few minutes ago! I'll update the answer when I have a moment

Comment: @randal'thor I've updated and reformatted. Hopefully that's better for you - sorry I'm still an amateur with the formatting!

Comment: Yep, looks great now and I've accepted.